# Find the probability that "A" wins the game.

Tags: probability, geometric-progressions

In a game, *A* and *B* play against each other. They throw a die alternatively until they get the face of **6**. Once one gets **6**, he wins. i.e., there is only one winner and they keep playing until one of them wins. 
*Consider that **B** plays first.*
What is the **probability of A winning**?

I don't even have a clue how to start, but I'm quite sure that it is concerned with the **geometric progression**. 
Pls do help me, any answers will be greatly appreciated. ( but if possible, pls do explain in detail )

Comment: No geometric progression is needed, actually... Conditioning on the first result and exploiting the symmetry of the problem, one sees that the probability $p$ that the second player wins is $$p=\frac16\cdot0+\frac56\cdot(1-p)$$ hence $$p=\ldots$$

Comment: Hint: the game effectively starts over each time it’s $A$’s turn.

Comment: Better hint: If A does not win with their first throw, then the game effectively starts over at the second throw, only, A and B inverted their roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $B$ play first, then the probability he/she wins in the first move is $\frac{1}{6}$. The probability that he/she does not win in the first move is $\frac{5}{6}$.

Suppose $B$ does not win in the first move (that has $\frac{5}{6}$ probability), in order for $B$ to win in the second, $A$ has to not win in their first move (that has $\frac{5}{6}$ probability) and then $B$ has to roll a six (that has $\frac{1}{6}$ probability).

Hence the probability of $B$ winning in their second move is $(\frac{5}{6})^2(\frac{1}{6})$.

Suppose $B$ does not win in their first move or second move...(that has ...probability)...

Answer (score 2):

He either wins in the first round ...or second round...or third round...so on.

It's probability will be

$$P=\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\times \left(\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac16 \right)+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3\times \left( \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\cdot \frac 16\right) \ldots $$

Now this sum can be calculated by solving the infinite GP sum

Comment: Why $(\frac{5}{6})^2$ in the last bracket?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Probability that A  doesn't win in the first 2 rounds, because if he did, the case will be repeatedly counted.

Comment: o_O that does make sense...

Answer (score 1):

For $A$ to win on their first turn we need $B$ to not get a 6 and $A$ to get a 6, for probability $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

For $A$ to win on their second turn, we need both to miss on their first try, $B$ to miss on their second try, and $A$ to get 6 on their second try, for probability $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

For $A$ to win on their third turn, we need $B$, $A$, $B$, $A$, $B$ to miss in that order and then $A$ to get a 6, for probability $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5\cdot\frac{1}{6}$.

This pattern continues infinitely so the probability $A$ wins the whole thing is $$\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^3\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\cdots = \dfrac{\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6}}{1-\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2} = \dfrac{5}{11}.$$

Answer (score 1):

B plays first, so if you want the probability of A winning, then B must not roll a 6. This has probability $\tfrac56$. Then A can win with probability $\tfrac16$, but alternatively he may lose, with probability $\tfrac56$, in which case it is back to the situation we started with. So we can represent the total probability with an infinite sum:

$$\begin{align}P(\text{A wins})&=\frac56\frac16+\left(\frac56\frac56\right)\frac56\frac16+\left(\frac56\frac56\right)\left(\frac56\frac56\right)\frac56\frac16+...\\&=\frac5{36}\frac1{1-\frac{25}{36}}\\&=\frac5{36-25}\\&=\frac5{11}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Are you sure you have calculated $P(B\:wins)$ and not $P(A\: wins)$?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah yes, this was just a typo, thanks